# How to create new variable in function using address

Tags: c, function, variables

When I create a new array using main array's base address I write this:

```
main()
{
    int a[]={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    display(a);
}

display(int anew[])
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ",anew[i]);
}
```

Why can I not do the same when trying to create a new int variable using address like this?

```
main()
{
    int a=7;
    display(&a);
}

display(int b)
{
    printf("%d ",b);
}
```

Comment: In the second code snippet: `display(&a);` -> `display(a);`

Comment: Because your `display(int b)` function is not accepting a pointer, but a value. You should change it into `display(int *b)` and then use `b` as `*b` (to get the value from the pointer). Note that in the first case, `int anew[]` is equivalent to `int *anew`, i.e. arrays cannot be passed by value, you always pass them as pointers.

Comment: It isn't clear what your goal is here. If you just want to pass an `int` to a function then you don't need to take its address.

Comment: The type of `&a` is `int*`. Your `display` function takes a plain `int` value as argument. Also, to get the value that a pointer is pointing to, you need to *dereference* it. Please take some time to refresh the chapters on pointers and arrays in your text books.

Comment: Doesn’t your compiler complain when a function is not declared before you use it? And, if you declare the function before you use it, doesn’t it complain that `&a` is not a suitable argument for an `int b` parameter? And doesn’t it complain that `display(int b)` does not declare a return type?

Comment: @TasminKhan I think it is a time to read the pointer chapter in your favourite C book\

Answer (score 1):

Because `display(int anew[])` is the same as `display(int *anew)` but `display(int *b)` is not the same as `display(int b)`. In C, when passed in a function, an array 'degenerates' into a pointer (to the first element). No such thing happens with an integer (only arrays and functions).

Answer (score 1):

With the line below you're passing the address of a to the display function. This will not work because `display(int b)` is expecting a parameter of type `int`.

```
display(&a); // should be replaced by display(a)
```

If you want to print the value of `a` in the display function by sending its address you should do the following:

```
main()
{
    int a=7;
    display(&a); //Pass the address of variable a
}

display(int *b) //Is expecting an address as argument
{
    printf("%d ", *b); //Print the value at that address
}
```